provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available
I just started learning ansible, when I try to start ping, this error appears
provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: demo

You need to check for below possible issues :

hosts.ini ensure the format is correct, it should be something like this:


[demo]
192.168.1.100 ansible_ssh_port=22 ansible_ssh_user=root



You are running from the directory in which hosts.ini is there
You have update the Ansible configuration file (ansible.cfg) to include the full path of hosts.ini, whic is specified using keyword inventory as in this example:


inventory = <full_path>/hosts.ini


